# series of products of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Assume that $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}$ and $(b_{n})_{n\geq 0}$ are non-negative sequences satisfying:

- $\sum_{n =0}^{+\infty}a_{n} = +\infty$.
- $(a_{n})_{n\geq 0}$ is decreasing and $\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_{n} = 0$.
- $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_{n}b_{n} < +\infty$.

Then it can be shown that $\liminf b_{n} = 0$. However, this proof does not need the second assumption.

My question is as follows. Can we get a stronger conclusion, say $\lim b_{n} = 0$, in my setting?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for example $a_n=1/n$ and $b_n=1$ if $n$ is a square, otherwise $b_n=0$. Then all three conditions are satisfied, but $\lim b_n$ does not exist.

Comment: beautiful example! thanks a lot :) So I guess $\liminf b_{n} = 0 $ is the best conclusion we can get in this setting.

Comment: Correct; you would need more restrictions in order to get $b_n\to0$.

Comment: which restriction do you think would guarantee $b_{n} \to 0$? I am interested in the case that we can conclude $b_{n}\to 0$.

Comment: It requires removing the constraint that $\lim a_n=0$. Otherwise, you can just define $b_n$ accordingly (like i did above) and get a counterexample.

Comment: I got it. By removing that assumption, we can bound $(a_{n})$ away from 0, and  then get the desired conclusion :)

Comment: Correct! ${}{}{}{}$